# In Dr. Racket, how would I display the 2 elements in a list in the opposite order?

Tags: list, racket

I want to write a function which displays 2 elements in a list in the opposite order. This is my code so far:

```
(define (reverse-order list)
  (cons (rest list) (cons (first list) empty)))
```

For some reason, this code is not working:
For example: If I type in

```
 (reverse-order (cons 1 (cons 2 empty)))
```

My desired output is

```
(cons 2 (cons 1 empty))
```

However, instead, I get

```
(cons (cons 2 empty) (cons 1 empty))
```

Any hints on how to go about solving this code will be very helpful.

Comment: I understand that this is some sort of exercise, the easiest way to accomplish way is to use the a built-in function `reverse`.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're taking the `rest` of the list, which is `'(2)`, not the second element `2`; and you should not call a parameter `list`, that clashes with a built-in procedure of the same name. Try this instead:

```
(define (reverse-order lst)
  (cons (second lst)
        (cons (first lst)
              empty)))
```

Or even simpler, and *now* you see why it was a bad idea to call the parameter `list`:

```
(define (reverse-order lst)
  (list (second lst) (first lst)))
```

Or just use the built-in `reverse` procedure :)

```
(define reverse-order reverse)
```

Anyway, it works as expected:

```
(reverse-order '(1 2))
=> '(2 1)
```